# Unexpected error when using feedparser.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, rss, feedparser, noaa

I have had great success parsing RSS feeds from the National Hurricane Center using the [feedparser](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/) module:

```
import feedparser
feedparser.parse('https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis-at.xml') #Works Fine
feedparser.parse('https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis-ep.xml') #Works Fine
```

However, when I try to read the superficially similar feed from the Central Pacific Hurricane Center, I generate a KeyError:

```
feedparser.parse('http://www.prh.noaa.gov/cphc/gis-cp.xml') #Doesn't work
```

Is this a bug with feedparser? Is the CPHC's feed malformed? Is there an option that I've forgotten to specify? It seems the trouble is that there isn't a key named 'where', but I don't know why this isn't a problem for the NHC feeds. The stack is reproduced below:

```
>>>  import feedparser
>>>  feedparser.parse('http://www.prh.noaa.gov/cphc/gis-cp.xml')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/feedparser.py", line 3956, in parse
    saxparser.parse(source)
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 111, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 125, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 217, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/tmp/build/80754af9/python_1516124163501/work/Modules/pyexpat.c", line 414, in StartElement
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 370, in start_element_ns
    AttributesNSImpl(newattrs, qnames))
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/feedparser.py", line 2031, in startElementNS
    self.unknown_starttag(localname, list(attrsD.items()))
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/feedparser.py", line 666, in unknown_starttag
    return method(attrsD)
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/feedparser.py", line 1500, in _start_gml_point
    self._parse_srs_attrs(attrsD)
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/feedparser.py", line 1496, in _parse_srs_attrs
    context['where']['srsName'] = srsName
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/feedparser.py", line 356, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'where'
```

Comment: I have the very same problem, did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I faced myself this issue and became my first opensource contribution :)

> Is this a bug with feedparser?

Yes, it was.

> Is the CPHC's feed malformed?

Also yes, or at least it doesn't follow the *GeoRSSS GML* model to the letter. If you check the [GMLPoint description](https://georss.org/gml.html#gmlpoint) you will see the following structure:

```
<georss:where>
  <gml:Point>
    <gml:pos>45.256 -71.92</gml:pos>
  </gml:Point>
</georss:where>
```

but the feed data is structured this way:

```
<gml:Point>
  <gml:pos>45.256 -71.92</gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
```

So that's why the `KeyError: 'where'` occurs, due to the absent of `where` tag.

This was fixed on `feedparser`'s `6.0.9` hotfix (see https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/pull/306)